# Python json file to json data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am doing like below,

```
 with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f) # to dict, is it possible to avoid this step
    json_data = json.dumps(data) # to json
```

Is it possible to read json file and assign json data to "json_data" variable directly instead of converting dict and dumping?

Comment: You mean, `json_data = f.read()`?

Comment: I tried it, seems formating comming wrongly

Comment: If you want specific formatting, I don't think you can avoid parsing the data.

Comment: Generally, data.load will convert the stream which contains JSON to a dict object. So you are taking JSON, converting it into an object and converting that into JSON. Formatting wise it should be the same as the source. but you will have to parse it (or use another method to "clean" the data) if you want to "beatify" it as bereal said.

Comment: You could still do it in one line, even though it's the same operation as you already have: `data = json.dumps(json.load(f))`. I guess it might make it less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file really does contain JSON, simply read the data to a string.

```
with open(filePath) as f:
    json_data = f.read()
```

Loading and dumping it like you're doing could be useful if you want to validate it on the way, of course.

Also, if the input JSON is e.g. indented or otherwise formatted in a non-standard way, loading and dumping it will normalize it. (`sort_keys=True` when dumping might also be useful.)

Answer (score 0):

You're deserializing, and then re-serializing the file's contents, which is mostly the same as... well, reading the file. Unless there's a specific reason you're doing this (i.e, formatting) you're probably better off just reading it with:

```
with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
    json_data = f.read()
```

Or, using pathlib's Path:

```
Path(filePath).read_text()
```